# SSRS Export Formatting Issue

Tags: excel, ssrs-2008

I have a SSRS report that shows one cell in tablix as percentage with 2 decimal points like 12.30%. When I export into excel the cell in the table shows #VALUE!. Could anyone please help me to fix that issue.

Comment: What is the expression for the Text Box's **Value**? What is the FORMAT property or Number Property? It should be 0.00% or P2.

Comment: When I passed through array list variable, it shows #Value!. I have changed that into array variable, it exports with correct format in excel. @Hannover,Thanks for the response.